# using search module in playframework,proper

Tags: java, search, module, lucene, playframework

I have a model `Item` that has a `name` and `description`.I need to allow the user to search for a part of string in name or description.Instead of doing this using an sql query,I thought of using the `search` module that can be installed for `playframework`.

Looking at the documentation for search module ,I put these annotations to the model

```
@Entity
@Indexed
class Item{

   @Field
   public String name;
   @Field
   public String description;

   public Date creationDate;
   ...
 ...
}
```

In application.conf ,I set

```
play.search.reindex=enabled
```

If I use an sql query like this

```
public static List<Item> getSearchResults(String kw){
    List<Item> items = null;
    if(kw!=null && kw.length()>0) {
        String trimkw = kw.trim().toLowerCase();
        String pattern = "%"+trimkw+"%";
        String query="select distinct b from Item b where (lower(name) like :pattern or lower(description) like :pattern)";
        items = Item.find(query).bind("pattern", pattern).fetch();
        System.out.println("getSearchResults():: items="+items.size());
    }
    return items;
}
```

This works properly,and handles the cases where input string is uppercase or lowercase etc.Also it will get results for partial strings ..
For example ,

```
I have items JavaRing ,Android
when the kw="JAvA"
the search returns a list containing JavaRing
```

I tried using Search module like this

```
import play.modules.search.Search;
import play.modules.search.Query;
...
String qstr = "name:"+trimkw+" OR description:"+trimkw;
System.out.println("query string="+qstr);
Query q = Search.search(qstr, Item.class);
items = q.fetch();
System.out.println("items="+items.size());
```

But this returns an empty list for the same keyword as I used in the previous case.

```
keyword = "JAvA"
query string=name:java OR description:java
items=0
```

Is there something wrong with the way I have coded the search string?

Answer (score 0):

Search module is based on Lucene. By default, Lucene searches for whole words. You didn't find anything because there isn't whole word 'java' in your fields. 
Using wildcards, for instance `name:java* OR description:java*` you'll fit your needs. You can find more examples [there](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/queryparsersyntax.html)

Answer (score 0):

Updated link is http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/queryparsersyntax.html

In this case, if the keyword is to be found anywhere, I assume string pattern needs to be modified from `%` to `*.`

ie. `String pattern = trimkw+"*";`

The rest of the code could remain the same.